# Login response failure displays error page instead of error message in login page nuxtjs

Tags: authentication, error-handling, nuxtjs3

I have used auth-nuxt for authentication. Authentication works fine for successful response. If response is not 200 then it shows error page instead of showing login page itself

This is my nuxt-config.js

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'data.accessToken',
          type: 'Bearer',
          maxAge: 'data.expiresIn'
          // 1800, // Token expiration time in seconds (30 minutes)
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'data.refreshToken',
          data: 'refreshToken',
          maxAge: false
          // 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // Refresh token expiration time in seconds (30 days)
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/admin/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'data.accessToken'
          },
          refresh: { url: '/refresh', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/admin/user-info', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
          logout: false // Optional, if your backend doesn't have a logout endpoint
        },
        autoFetchUser: true
      }
    },
    // Set autoRefresh option to true
    autoRefresh: true,
    autoLogout: true, // Optional, if you want to automatically log out when the access token expires
    redirect: {
      login: '/sign-in', // if login required
      logout: '/sign-in', // after logout
      home: '/' // after login
    }
  },
```

I have used

```
 "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
```

The following is my login method

```
 handleLogin(loginData) {
    this.$auth
      .loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: loginData.email,
          username: loginData.email,
          password: loginData.password
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // The promise is resolved, but we need to check the status of the response
        if (response && response.status === 200) {
          // Successful login
          console.log('Login API response:', response)
          this.snackbartext = 'Logged in successfully'
          this.snackbar = true
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$router.push('/')
          }, 1000)
        } else {
          // Login failed, handle the error
          console.error('Login API error:', response)
          this.snackbartext = 'An error occurred during login. Please try again.'
          this.snackbar = true
          // Handle other error scenarios, if needed
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // The promise is rejected (login failed)
        console.error('Login API error:', error)
        this.snackbartext = 'An error occurred during login. Please try again.'
        this.snackbar = true
        // Handle other error scenarios, if needed
      })
```

The following is response from api, for unsuccessful api response

```
{
    "data": "",
    "message": "User not found for user name : admin@gmail.com",
    "success": false
}
```

The login error is not caught in .catch hook instead it is catching at .then hook. I am not sure why this is happening

The following are successful response from api and it is redirecting to dashboard as well

```
{
    "data": {
        "accessToken": "abc",
        "refreshToken": "abc",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 6,
            "firstName": "abc",
            "lastName": "PM",
            "email": "abc+14@abc.com",
        },
        "loginFirstTime": true
    },
    "message": "Success",
    "success": true
}
```

For other failure responses, default error page is loading but url remains same as login form and also it call user info fetch api and it also shows error
Actually i am new to nuxtjs.  Version used is nuxt 2, vuetify 2
For most of errors it shows error page instead of showing snackbar.
How can i handle the issues